# An undefined reference error for files in a directory in c++

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I'm working on a project, and inside of the project I've separated my own classes and functions into a directory called base_lib. When compiling the project, I keep getting an undefined reference error for one of the classes in this library. I have been trying to find the answer on many different forums and ultimately just decided to ask it myself. The code:

stack.h

```
#ifndef __STACK_H
#define __STACK_H


namespace stacker
{
/*******
My code here
 *******/
}


#endif
```

stack.cpp

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename var>
stacker::Stack<var>::Stack()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}
```

fix.h

```
#ifndef __FIX_H
#define __FIX_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


namespace fixes
{
/*******
My code here
 *******/
}

#endif
```

fix.cpp

```
#include "fix.h"
#include "base_lib/stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
using namespace stacker;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fix.h"
#include "base_lib/functions.h"

using namespace fixes;
using namespace mine;
using namespace std;
```

The compiler error

```
C:\...:fix.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `stacker::Stack<char>::Stack()'
...
```

Does anyone have any tips or tricks?

Comment: Identifiers with a double underscore, identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter, and identifiers starting with an underscore in the global namespace are reserved. Using them causes undefined behavior, so change the name of your header guard macros.

Comment: I just added those in the past 10-15 minutes. Unfortunately, it wasn’t the solution  to the problem.

Comment: Just because it's didn't cause this specific problem doesn't mean it's not *a* problem. Your code has undefined behavior because of this, which means the C++ standard doesn't place any restrictions on the behavior of your program. You never know when using a reserved identifiers might cause some weird cryptic errors because it conflicted with identifiers defined by the system. I've seen that happen here before.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a template in a C++ file instead of a header file.

This means the template will not compile, thus the error you are getting.

Read here: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)